Why in plural form I see "знака", and not "знаки"?
I cannot figure it out -- let's start from wiktionary: знак In plural form there is no "знака", yet I noticed it in real life, and quick search gives example right at the wikipedia page: Параллельные тональности.
On one hand it uses phrases like "имеющие идентичные ключевые знаки" -- which corresponds to the listed plural forms, and also such as "соль минор (2 знака бемоля)" which puzzles me. Why not "соль минор (2 знаки бемоля)"?

When we have 2, 3 or 4 (or a numeral that ends with these numerals, like 22, 23, 24, 32, etc... or оба/обе) + noun, if the nominative is expected, then the numeral is in the nominative and the noun in the genitive singular.
Example: Вот два мальчика.
See also this related question (by myself): https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/27524/два-светлые-глаза
